# How do transition labelling in Pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

The old dataframe exist at least two column `os_first` and `os_last`, and I need to add new column 'to_ios'

Here's the value:

- `undefined` if `os_first` or `os_last` is null
- `1` if 'os_last' is'iOS', and `os_first` is not null
- `0` for others

Here's the pandas code:

```
df.loc[(df['os_first'].isnull()==True) | (df['os_last'].isnull()==True), 'to_ios']= 'undefined'

df.loc[(df['os_first'].notnull()==True) & (df['os_last']=='iOS') , 'to_ios'] = '1'

df.loc[~(df['to_ios'].isin(['undefined','1'])) , 'to_ios'] = '0'
```

How to write to Pyspark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use when() and otherwise() for this.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lit, when

df = df.withColumn('to_ios', 
              when(col('os_first').isNull() | col('os_last').isNull(), lit('undefined'))
             .when(col('os_first').isNotNull() & (col('os_last') == 'iOS'), lit('1'))
             .otherwise(lit('0')))
```